# Viewing Performance test results

Tags: jenkins-workflow

Is it possible to configure post-build actions as part of workflow (immediately after your DSL script completes, I would guess?) In my case, I'd like to display JMeter Performance test results using the Performance Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Workflows do not have “post-build actions” as such. There are just steps you can run, including the `step` metastep for running build steps and publishers from plugins without an explicit Workflow dependency but which have been updated to implement the `SimpleBuildStep` interface available in newer versions of Jenkins core.

[This document](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#build-steps-and-post-build-actions) summarizes the status of compatibility for plugins that people have bothered to file issues about. The Performance plugin does not seem to be listed currently. If you do file such an RFE, be sure to mark it with the `workflow` label for proper tracking.

Comment: now the plugin is contained in the compatibility list and they created a Jira issue in January but there has been not progress so far: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32650  any workarounds / other plugins that can be used